# Debugger wont launch .netcore application on Mac Only. (But works on Windows)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to run the .Net Core Launch(web) debugger. The debugger launches but the application never runs and thus the breakpoints never hits. Here are my launch.json settings. I have tried on a windows machine and it works perfectly fine but for some reason on the mac the debugger fails to launch and ends up not working. In the console, the debugger loads fine so I am not getting any errors.

```
{
   // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
   // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
   // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
   "version": "0.2.0",
   "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/abc/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/abc.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src/abc",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            },
            
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where is your breakpoint set? Have you tried hitting the endpoint anyhow, even though it doesn't seem to launch itself in a browser?

Comment: Breakpoint is set on application start, to ensure it will get hit. I tried navigating to my localhost page and it does not load which tells me it never builds. My dotnet run does work and build properly.

Comment: If you use the terminal to run it manually, does that work? In terminal, navigate to the project folder and type `dotnet run` (I think that's it). If that starts and you can get to the app's URL in your browser, maybe try deleting / rebuilding your launch.json?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

Commenting out the TCP Output in my eventFlowConfig.json file fixed the issue.
The application uses websocket and seems like theres a bug in the mac client when trying to output it.

Specifically, under outputs of eventFlowConfig.json, I had to comment out the type:"socketOutput" section.

Comment: "a bug in the mac client", unlikely. It's far more likely you're trying to open a protected OS socket, for which you need admin privileges on a Mac.

Comment: Interesting, is there a way to allow admin privileges on a mac for the protected OS socket?

Comment: So currently i'm running the debugger through the VSCode UI, I looked around and didnt see a command to run the debugger through terminal. Assuming I could, id do sudo -run debugger command- but In the case that I cant what would be the appropriate alternative?

Comment: The easiest way by far is to just `sudo code path/to/project`, ie to make VSCode itself `root`. Any child it spawns inherits its environment. As to spawning custom debuggers, you can also do that, it's in one of the vs.code.*.json files i believe.